# object recognition in image processing

Tags: object, image-processing, gesture-recognition

i am totally new to image processing..
wat im going to do is to identify if the object is in the image...its object recognition or identification...cud u pls giv me a code for this...i need this for my project..

thank u and Godspeed!!

Comment: If you're new to something, you need to learn about it. Demanding that other people just "give you the code" is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: You can try examining [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library.

Comment: tell us more about the problem.  what object are you trying to recognise?  what are the images like?  give examples.  also, do what skaffman said.

Answer (score 1):

my project is also object recognition but it is as object recognition uing edge detection and hisogram processing techniques... instead of using ANN i have moved to it ... there is no specific code i found yet other than based on 2d correlation in mathwork which is running taking 2 images as input and identify / highlights the recognized part in original image but its for object performing pixel by pixel match..